# XEN: How to change domU-persistence?

Tags: persistence, virtualization, xen, transient, libvirt

I have several running Xen-domUs, now I want to manage them using libvirt / virsh and noticed they all are defined as transient VMs.

Can I somehow change them to be persistent?

Answer (score 0):

That's the difference between:

`virsh create`

and:

`virsh define` and `virsh start`.

The first one will create a non-persistent VM.

Comment: Thanks that's good to know! But can I create a persistent VM out of an already running transient one?

Comment: turns out it was as simple as dumping the xml of the previously created domU and defining it - did not even need to restart the VM `virsh dumpxml vmname > vmname.xml && virsh define vmname.xml`